# Ubuntu 14.04 php7.1 sqlite driver could not find to install

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php7, sqlite

My Laravel application has test environment to run on sqlite database but it's says the driver is missing and I could not find any solution to install the driver. Would someone help? I have the following PDO exception:

```
$ php artisan migrate --database=testing
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_sqlite3.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_sqlite3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is past end of life. Upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: really ubuntu?. dll o  linux?

Comment: Which ubuntu release is required? I have upgraded to 16.04 LTS but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My php7.1-sqliite3 driver was missing and it did not support (not even by any ppa) before the OS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When upgraded the driver installation was possible now it's running testcases with phpunit in Laravel 5.6.*